# What is the `alignSelf` equivalent to the *main-axis* in react-native?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I wanna center absolutely positioned control both vertically and horizontally (without wrapping it in a View) ... `alignSelf` could center it in the cross-axis...

So what is the `alignSelf` equivalent to the **main-axis** in react-native?